# Diophantine equation of second degree $x^2+y^2+z^2=2t^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to solve this Diophantine equation of second degree? 
Solution, references, anything. I will be very grateful.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2t^2$$

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly, there are infinitely many solutions. x=y=t z=0. Or do you mean other solutions?

Comment: Yes. Another solutions. (x,y,z,t): (1,1,4,3); (3,4,5,5); (2,2,8,6)

Comment: Let x= t-2 y= t+1 Then $z^2=2t-5$  For some t 2t-5 is a perfect square( All odd squares are of this form). So infinitely many solutions again.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee, if you also explin how you came up with that, i would make a _great_ answer

Comment: Extreme amounts of guesswork. I thought of my first solution, the one with x=t y=t z=0.Then, I thought of slightly changing x and y, to make $z^2$  a linear function of t t-1 and t+1 don't work, so I went for the next one.

Comment: There are more such linear functions as choices for x and y giving many solutions that are not of this form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parametrization of $a^2+b^2+c^2=2d^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501690/parametrization-of-a2b2c2-2d2)

Answer (score 2):

You can start with $x,y,z$ any Pythagorean triple, then take $t=z$.  There are more.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix $z$ at $t$, and vary $x$ and $y$,

After fixing $z$ at $t$, the equation becomes,

$$x^2+y^2=t^2\dots(1)$$

One solution of this equation is $(0,t)$

$(1)$ is the equation of a circle in $x-y$ plane with radius $t$.

Inorder to find all the solution of $(1)$ we follow the following method,

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be some other solution,

We will draw the line connecting $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(0,t)$,

Equation of this line would be $\frac{y_0-t}{x_0}=m,m\in R$

$\Rightarrow y_0=mx_0+t\dots (2)$

Putting this in $(1)$ we have,

$x_0^2(1+m^2)+2mx_0t+t^2=t^2$

$\Rightarrow x_0^2(1+m^2)+2mx_0t=0$

$x_0(1+m^2)+2mt=0$ Considering $x_0\ne 0$ as then we get the same point$(0,t)$

$\Rightarrow x_0=-\frac{2mt}{1+m^2}$

Putting this into (2) we get,

$y_0=\frac{t(1-m^2)}{1+m^2}$

Now $(x_0,y_0)$ was any arbitrary solution of this equation.For each such solution we will get a line . And for each such line we will get another solution(quite eacy to see), which implies if we consider all $m\in R$ we will get all the solutions of (1).

Thus one set of solution of the original equation is, $(-\frac{2mt}{1+m^2},\frac{t(1-m^2)}{1+m^2},t)$ $m\in R$.

Comment: But $x,y,z,t$ are supposed to be integral for a Diaphontine equation.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ross Millikan's suggestion, let $m$ and $n$ be any two integers, and then let
$$x = m^2 - n^2$$
$$y = 2mn$$
$$z = m^2 + n^2$$
$$t = z$$
Then $x,y,z$ form a Pythagorean triple, which means that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$. This gives 
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2z^2 = 2t^2$. There are other ways to generate Pythagorean triples, of course; this is just the one that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that so many and so this kind of equation vozyatsya.Takogo vsegda.To elementary equations are solved there can always say under what factors can Met solutions in integers and when they are not.
Okay. equation:

$X^2+Y^2+Z^2=2T^2$

Solutions can be written:

$X=(p-q)^2+q^2-2sp$

$Y=2(q+s)(q+s-p)$

$Z=p^2+2s^2-2p(q+s)$

$T=(p-q)^2+(q+s)^2+s(s-2p)$

$p,s,q$ - any integers any sign.

Answer (score -1):

For every $t$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=2t^2$, defines a 3-Dimensional sphere with radius $\sqrt{2}t$. Thus, every point on the surface of the sphere is a solution for the diophantine equation. If you are interested in characterizing all the solutions, this should help
\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{2}t \\
x&=r\sin{(\theta)}\cos(\phi) \\
y&=r\sin{(\theta)}\sin(\phi) \\
z&=r\cos{(\theta)} \\
\end{align} 
where $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. Thus, substituting any value for $t$ , $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the above mentioned equations will give you a solution.

Comment: But $x,y,z,t$ are supposed to be integral for a Diaphontine equation.

Comment: yes, I just realized my mistake. But the op has accepted it as an answer. Thanks for this.