How to find three numbers such that the sum of any two of them as well as the total sum is a perfect square?
Chistyakov, problem # 51.
One must find three numbers such that the sum of any two of them and also the total sum would be a perfect square.
The author does not specify that numbers must be natural, but I guess they must probably be. (Or one of them could equal zero.)

I think I should show my thoughts and efforts in order me trying to solve this problem.
I tried denoting our three numbers with the letters a, b and c.
We have a system of four equations:

a + b = p²;
a + c = q²;
b + c = r²;
a + b + c = s².


I tried adding all four equations together. We get: 3a + 3b + 3c = p² + q² + r² + s²;
a + b + c = (p² + q² + r² + s²)/3.
But, on the other hand, this also equals s² (see equation #4). So we have:
(p² + q² + r² + s²)/3 = s²  |*3 (I decided to multiply both parts by 3 in order to get rid of the fraction);
p² + q² + r² + s² = 3s²;
p² + q² + r² = 3s² – s²;
p² + q² + r² = 2s².
Here, I don't really know what I can do. I even tried to solve it using Mathway. Or Mathforyou. As the result, it just expresses one variable, e. g. p, in relation to other three. So I really don't know how to solve such an equation which still has four different variables. [Should I manually try different p's, q's and r's in order to substitute them into the equation so I can find s? This would take a zillion years!]
However, when I tried to post this question on another site, they instantly gave me a ton of solutions. I guess the answerers used a computer. They didn't provide any explanation at all. I wonder if it possible to find all the solutions without any computer/calculator usage.

As it turns out, every number of the form $2s^2$ can be written as the sum of three squares $2s^2=p^2+q^2+r^2$. (This is a consequence of a tidy, but somewhat deep, theorem of Legendre.) So if we simply set $a=s^2-r^2$ and $b=s^2-q^2$ and $c=s^2-p^2$, we get the desired numbers with $a+b=p^2$ and $a+c=q^2$ and $b+c=r^2$.
(Admittedly, this doesn't guarantee that $a,b,c$ are positive if that matters; but in practice there will be lots of choices of $p,q,r$ and many of them will lead to positive $a,b,c$.)

Also $2s^2 = p^2 + q^2 + r^2$    (primitive)  has a parametrization  of sorts    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501690/parametrization-of-a2b2c2-2d2/1502745#1502745   similar to Pythagorean Quadruples.  If nothing else, expressing your $s$  as $t^2 + u^2 +2v^2 + 2 w^2$  is a quicker brute force search thatn the original.
